# Proving that certain functional has a positive lower bound

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, optimization, calculus-of-variations

Let $I =[a,b]$, and let $\theta$ denote a smooth function $I \to (0, \pi)$. Consider the functional

$$ J(\theta) = \int_{a}^{b} \frac{\left(F(s,\theta(s))^{2}+G(s,\theta'(s))^{2}\right)^{2}}{F(s,\theta(s))^{2}}\, ds, $$

where both $F$ and $G$ are continuous (in fact, smooth) functions.

**Question.** Suppose that $G(s,\theta'(s)) =0$ whenever $F(s,\theta(s)) =0$ and that the set of points where $F(s,\theta(s))=0$ is nowhere dense in $I$. Can we then conclude that $J$ has a *positive* lower bound?

Intuitively, it seems reasonable to expect the answer to be affirmative, but I am lacking a proof.

The functional $J$ is interesting to me because it measures the bending energy of an infinitely narrow developable strip in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: Are $F$ and $G$ functionals or just functions? As written, they look like functions.

Comment: @KBS Yes, they are functions. I edited the question.

Comment: @KBS Well, $G$ is a function of $\theta'$, not $\theta$.

Comment: If you want to prove the existence of a positive lower bound, then you will need to use the calculus of variation to find the $\theta$ that minimizes your functional $J$,  and show that this minimum is positive. This can be done using the calculus of variations and the Euler-Lagrange equation; see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations